# Is this a native iOS design?

Tags: interface-design, android, ios

I have a question regarding this design:

[image]

Is this a native iOS design? I'm fairly new to iOS, so I don't know if this is native iOS or not. It does look to me it's Android layout that would need some customization to look the same on iOS. Am I correct?

Would anyone be able to point what would be the items native to Android that don't exist (would require customization) on iOS?

I got a nice answer from Duncan C on this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660005/how-to-mimic-android-bar-on-ios

But now I'd like to validate the whole layout in order to be better prepared.

Comment: What do you mean by 'native design'? Are you asking if the app is a native app in terms of code? Or are you asking if the design adheres to iOS's style guidelines?

Comment: @DA01 The second (If it adheres to iOS's style guidelines) I'm almost sure is false, am I correct? But my question regarding whether it is native is about the components. To me it looks like an Android app with some customization. It doesn't look like a "universal" app (that takes both systems components into account), neither like a native iOS app. I'm asking here to get some help from experts, since I'm a developer, not a designer/UX professional.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm behind in what the current iOS guidelines are these days (they seem to change fast). But consider if you really need to adhere to it 100% in the first place. Most apps out there take liberties and I'd usually argue do what's right for your app first and foremost.

Comment: @DA01 Definitely. That's why I'm asking here. I'd like to understand if the effort required to implement those using iOS would be worth the trouble or if I'd be better off asking for an iOS adaptation. :) Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tab bars in IOS go at the bottom of the screen. 
Check out these IOS [Human interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/tab-bars/), as they call it, 
from Apple. They have guidelines for all the components that are available to the software engineer. 
Keep in mind that the best practice is not to create your own components, but to use components from this list, in order to build your UI. This helps not only the developer, but also it leads to great UX.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you elaborate a little bit more regarding this specific layout? I'm asking because I think there are few components there not native, like the hamburger menu and the tab bar (as you mentioned). Thanks.

Comment: Regarding the tab bar, it should be at the bottom. The hamburger menu, AKA side menu , is both IOS and Android, but many are against it , on both platforms. Spotify used to have it and they have ditched it since May 2016.